# Rails - ensuring only one simultaneous controller hit per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, concurrency, debouncing

**tl;dr** - Is there a way to ensure that a given Rails controller action stops executing when another simultaneous request from the same user comes in?

In my Rails/Angular app, I make requests to the Foursquare API from the client-side. Because they need to be authenticated, and my authentication information should remain secure, I pass these requests through a Rails controller in my own app.

For a more in-depth description of the architecture of this, check out [this semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836102/securely-making-authenticated-api-requests-from-client/29836917#29836917).

My concern, as elaborated there, is that each request to this internal controller takes up server time (and on Heroku, ties up a dyno). I'd tried to make the action as fast as possible, but I'd still like to reduce the amount the server is tied up.

The amount the server is tied up is exacerbated by the real-time nature of the search I'm doing. The request is sent out to my server as a user types, not on enter or anything, because I wanted to allow for auto-suggestion.

I'm debouncing the user input (0.4 seconds), so a the request isn't made til a user briefly stops typing. But if a user pauses a few times while typing, and a request goes out each time, this can quickly cause multiple dynos to get used.

> More concretely, assuming a roughly ~1.3s API response time from Foursquare, imagine this scenario: A user types "ameri", then waits 0.4 seconds, then types "can", then waits 0.4 seconds, then types " beauty", completing their query. This would send three separate requests, all of which would need to be handled by different dynos, because none of the requests have a chance to return before the next comes in.

This would either cost me a ton of money (if I have a bunch of users, that means a large number of dynos to protect against concurrency timeouts) or cause really annoying waits on the user front.

**So my thought** would be that it would be awesome if I could essentially do a retroactive debounce on the server side, by terminating any running requests to Foursquare coming from that user before sending a new request out. That would mean that in the above concrete example, while 3 requests started, only the last request would come back, because the first two would be dropped midstream when a new one came in.

> I was thinking of storing some variable in `session` for each that would be true when a request was executing. Then, the next request wouldn't go out if it was triggered. But that's actually sort of the opposite of what I want, because I want the **original** request to get canceled when the new one comes in. I just don't know how to access that request from within the latter on.

This feels complicated, so I'm guessing it may be impossible (particularly as each controller action is responded to by a new controller instance), but does anyone know a way to cancel controller actions if the same action is hit by the same user again while the first request is getting resolved?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the concurrency question, but wouldn't disabling fields momentarily with gimmicky loading spinner work just as well with less complication here?

Comment: I'll definitely need a loading spinner though for sure. But I think it would be super intrusive for the user if they were just pausing to figure out how to spell the word or something, and a spinner blocked them from continuing for a second.